# Combining bottom navigator and top navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

The AppNavigator and TopBarNavigator should be displayed all the time on the app. The problem is that I can't get the topbarnav to show up without adding it to the appNavigator. The problem with that is that it adds an extra tab, which I don't want at the bottom.

```
const AppNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
    {
      Insights: {screen: Insights},

      Incidents: {screen: googleMapsImages},

      Plus: {screen: Addhazard},

      'Team alerts': {screen: TeamAlerts},

      More: {screen: Main},
    },{
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: 'green',
      inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
    },
  }
);

const Drawernavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    BottomNavigator: {screen: AppNavigator},
    Team: {screen: YourTeam},
  }
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(Drawernavigator);
class App extends Component {
  render(){
   return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <AppContainer />
          </View>
            );
      }
    }
```

A good example is the app you can download here --> https://safetyculture.com/spotlight/

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? It doesn't make sense to render only one tab in material tab navigator.

Comment: I changed the code, I copied a wrong section of something I was testing. Anyhow: I want the drawernavigator to be accecible all the time, but now the drawer shows the BottomNavigator and Team, while I only want it to show the Team. The problem is that I don't understand how to combine them all together without displaying all the tabs. (https://safetyculture.com/spotlight/) the app they build is a good example of what I want to achieve.